# Laravel pagination links() styling missing on prod

Tags: php, css, laravel, pagination, vite

I published the vendor pagination and am using a slightly modified `vendor/pagination/default.blade.php` and I have all my styling in dev (macos laptop).

(I have to use my own view pagination because the site does not use/want a css framework.)

I push to prod (using git deploy, deploy script below) and I get my pagination -- but I am missing all my styling. I can add styling inline and it will show up on prod, but it isn't recognizing my styles in my app.css file. Clearing the cache doesn't solve this.

I assume it is when things get compiled with Vite? Is the pagination view getting rendered in some manner that it doesn't have access to my stylesheet?

Update, here is my deploy script (using Laravel Forge):

```
git pull origin $FORGE_SITE_BRANCH

$FORGE_COMPOSER install --no-dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

( flock -w 10 9 || exit 1
    echo 'Restarting FPM...'; sudo -S service $FORGE_PHP_FPM reload ) 9>/tmp/fpmlock

if [ -f artisan ]; then
    $FORGE_PHP artisan migrate --force
fi

npm run build

php artisan view:cache
```

Comment: When it is time to deploy your app for production, simply run the `vite build` command.

Answer (score -1):

use `npm install` and  `npm run build`

Comment: Thanks but the deploy script already does that. It is a slightly modified Forge deploy script, I will update my post with it. The whole site needs `npm run build` and everything else works, except css for pagination.